# jQuery Remove elements where the content is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the elements where there is no content. For example this is my HTML markup:

I have the html markup in a jquery variable say var myhtml and I am not sure of any specific tags in it.

```
<h1>
    <u>
        <strong></strong>
    </u>
    <u>
        <strong>Read This Report Now
            <strong></strong> ??
        </strong>
    </u>
</h1>
```

As we can see that above markup

```
<u>
    <strong></strong>
</u>
```

is empty and hence this should be removed from the markup. Say I have the above markup in a variable `myhtml`. How can I do this?

I am not sure if the element will be either

```
"<u>" or "<em>" or "<i>" or "<div>" or "<span>"
```

.. It can be anything.

Comment: when you say elements is it just u tag or all elements in the documents?

Comment: If you have a html string and you need to remove the empty elements see how works without `jQuery` in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25440189/2389232). I have updated it although I know that it was marked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can search all elements and remove which is empty.

```
$('*').each(function(){ // For each element
    if( $(this).text().trim() === '' )
        $(this).remove(); // if it is empty, it removes it
});
```

See how works!: http://jsfiddle.net/qtvjj3oL/

**UPDATED**:

You also can do it without `jQuery`:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if( elements[i].textContent.trim() === '' )
        elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
}
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qtvjj3oL/1/

**UPDATED 2**:

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440097/jquery-remove-elements-where-the-content-is-empty/25440189#comment39691459_25440137), you have the html in a variable, you can do it:

```
// the html variable is the string wich contains the html
// We make a fake html
var newHtml = document.createElement('html');
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
newHtml.innerHTML = html;
frag.appendChild(newHtml);

var elements = newHtml.getElementsByTagName("*");

// Remove the emptys elements
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if( elements[i].textContent.trim() === '' )
        elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
}

html = newHtml.innerHTML; // now reset html variable
```

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/qtvjj3oL/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot Snake.. For your help and support.. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
 $("u").each(function () {      // if remove all, you can select all element $("*")           
    var x = $(this).text().trim();
    if (x == "") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

IF you want remove everything simply you can use **[empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)**  selector  then remove it

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z9wkLsa0/)

Comment: This solution is working but I forgot to mention one thing in my question. I am not sure if the element is either "<u>" or "<em>" or "<i>" or "<div>" or "<span>" .. It can be anything.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question that I have the html in a jquery variable.
var myhtml = $(".mydiv").html();

And now from the html which I will get I have to clean it.

Comment: According to the last comment I have made a remover from string. See how remove the empty elements from string without `jQuery` in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25440189/2389232).

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery**

It searches all elements and remove all blank elements (ie: `<span></span>`), all elements which contains a simple space (ie: `<span> </span>`) and all elements which contains only a `&nbsp;` (ie: `<span>&nbsp;</span>`)

```
$(".mydiv *").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
        $this.remove();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7L4WZ/389/

Comment: As I mentioned in my question that I have the html in a jquery variable.
var myhtml = $(".mydiv").html();

Comment: Thank you very much! I am using it!

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
$( ":empty" ).remove();
```

or

```
$( "u:empty" ).remove();
```

if specific

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` and `remove()` for this

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == ""
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your html is already in a variable `myhtml` here is how you would do it:

```
$('*', myhtml).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == '';
}).remove();
```